# How do I add a self signed openssl x509 certificate to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, openssl, x509

I have created my certificate as follows;

`openssl req -nodes -new -text -out ~/server.req -keyout ~/server.key`

`openssl req -x509 -in ~/server.req -text -key ~/server.key -out ~/server.crt`

I now need to add it to Tomcat, clearly I can't use the Tomcat docs example of

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in server.crt -inkey server.key -out server.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile serverCA.crt -caname root -chain`

because it is self signed.  So how do I add it to Tomcat?

Comment: Java cryptography is designed so that it _requires_ a valid chain back to a trusted CA. The only way to get Java to accept a self-signed cert is to add the root CA certificate with which you signed the cert to the trusted certificate list in Java's default keystore.  I did this several years ago and it wasn't easy.  Unfortunately I don't have the time right now to find my old notes.  I hope somebody else can provide details.

Comment: Ok, cheers I'll see what I can find related to adding the root CA certificate

Comment: @tojofo:What are these certificates?You have created them with some CN and self-signed?

Answer (score 0):

The example provided in the Tomcat documentation will work, you will just need to create your own local Certificate Authority to create your certificate against.

I've found this tutorial useful in the past: http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/ca.shtml

The following commands from that page:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out CA.key <key_size>
openssl req -new -key CA.key -x509 -days 1095 -out ../certs/CA.crt
```

Where `CA.crt` will be what is used when creating the your cert with the `-CAfile` flag

Hope that helps.

Comment: I created the CA.crt but when attempting to add using a command of the form in the Tomcat docs and listed above I still get; `Error self signed certificate getting chain.`

Answer (score 0):

I found my old notes.

You can't use a self-signed cert.  What you have to do is go the longer route and generate a "real" local CA, as follows:

Generate a private key for the CA

```
openssl genrsa -out CA/cakey.pem -des3 2048
```

Generate a certificate-signing request for root CA certificate

```
openssl req -new -config openssl.cnf -key CA/cakey.pem -out CA/cacert.req
```

Self-Sign the CA Certificate

```
openssl x509 -req -in CA/cacert.req -extfile openssl.cnf \
    -extensions v3_ca -signkey CA/cakey.pem -out CA/cacert.pem -days 3650
```

Generate a Java keystore containing the CA certificate for your client:

```
keytool -importcert -file CA/cacert.pem -keystore client.jks -storepass [password]
```

Comment: Well now I have managed to get the key in there but on startup I get the following error  `java.io.IOException: jsse.invalid_ssl_conf`  Caused by `No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled`  The docs suggest an incorrect alias, specifying `keyAlias` doesn't resolve it, also there is only one key and by default it should read that.  Do I need to use an AJP Connector?